# Can we show only results of some epochs in tqdm?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am training a NN and use tqdm for showing the results. However, the bad thing is that it shows the results for every epoch. This is too many as I want to train NN for atleast 500 epochs.
Is there any way that I show the results for e.g. only each 10 steps i.e. "if epoch //10 ==0"? If its possible, what code and where to add it?

```
for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    ### =====TRAINING=====
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0
    with tqdm(train_dataloader, unit="batch") as train_epoch_pbar:
        for data, labels in train_epoch_pbar:
            train_epoch_pbar.set_description(f"Epoch {epoch}")
            if torch.cuda.is_available():
               data, labels = data.cuda(), labels.cuda()
```

.
.
.

```
print(
            f"======= Epoch: {epoch} Average Training loss: {avg_epoch_loss:.4f} ======="
        )
        train_loss_list.append(avg_epoch_loss)
```

Comment: You should be able to simply put the `set_description` call (or the print statement, depending on which of the two you mean with 'results') in an if statement so it only gets called every x epochs.

Comment: I see your answer is in right direction. But it is still vague to me. Can you please tell it more accurately i.e. where to add it and how write it?